# How do I store/fetch Json objects from my browser's local storoge

Tags: javascript

I am a novice in JavaScript and I just need some help for a project that requires JavaScript. I need to store Json objects in the browser.

How would I store a Json object in local storage of a browser?

Also, how would I retrieve it?

Here is what I have right now:

```
//Json object
var obj{
   "name":"Quandale Dingle",
   "age":24,
   "team":"Seahawks"
}

//Storing it in local storage
localStorage.setItem(obj);
```

I checked my console for the getItem, and I would not get any result.

Comment: That's not a "json object". That's just a javascript object. As for how you use localStorage: it stores strings. So you turn your data into a string, save it, and parse it when you need to load it.

Comment: You should Stringify obj by: JSON.stringify(obj) and then add it to local storage using with an associated key.

Comment: To fetch it you would have to use: localStorage.getItem(<key>) and then  parse it into a Json object using JSON.parse(jsonString).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
   "name":"Quandale Dingle",
   "age":24,
   "team":"Seahawks"
}
```

**Set**

```js
localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify(obj))
```

**Get**

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo'))

// {name: 'Quandale Dingle', age: 24, team: 'Seahawks'}
```